# Induction proof for proving the convergence of a series by Leinbiz

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, induction

I have to study the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\ln{n}}{n}$.

To do this I have thought to use the Leibniz rule, so I have to verify if:

1. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln{n}}{n}=0$, and it is true.
2. if $\frac{\ln{n}}{n}$ is decreasing.

For the last point I have problems: I want to apply the induction (so no computing the derivative of the correspoding function $\frac{\ln{x}}{x}$). I have understood that this is true maybe for $n\geq 3$, to prove this I have to observe that:

for $n=3$ $\frac{\ln{n}}{n}>\frac{\ln{n+1}}{n+1}$;
Now assuming that $\frac{\ln{n}}{n}>\frac{\ln{n+1}}{n+1}$ $\textbf{how can I prove that $\frac{\ln{n+1}}{n+1}>\frac{\ln{n+2}}{n+2}$ concluding so the proof by induction?}$

Then after this proof the Leibniz criterion tells me that the series is convergent.

Comment: $((\ln x)/x)'=(1-\ln x)/x^2<0$ for $x>e.$

Comment: Thanks, this is useful but I want a proof by induction, without using the derivative of the corresponding function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Claim:** For all $n \ge 3$, the following is true:
> $$\frac{\ln n}{n} \ge \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1}$$

**Proof:** Rewite the claim as follows
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\ln n}{n} &\ge \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} \\
\sqrt[n]{n} &\ge \sqrt[n+1]{n+1} \\ 
n^{n+1} &\ge (n+1)^n \\ 
n &\ge \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n && (*)
\end{align}$$
Note that the RHS is an increasing sequence. Here goes the proof:

> Let $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = \dots = a_{n+1} = 1+1/n$. Applying AM-GM, we have
> $$\sqrt[n+1]{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} \le 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \iff \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le \left(1+ \frac{1}{1+n}\right)^{n+1}$$

However, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n = e$. Therefore, for all $n\ge 3$ we have
$$n \ge 3 > e \ge \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
which proves $(*)$ and hence the claim.

---

You can also use induction where AM-GM is used here.

Comment: Wow very very thanks! Two things:1) we prove that $\sqrt[n]{n}\geq \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$ because $\sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\frac{\ln{n}}{n}}$ and the exponential function is increasing, right? 2) $e\geq (1+1/n)^n$ since the sequence converges to this and it is increasing so $e$ it is a supremum, right?

Comment: If you expand $(1+1/n)^n$ by the Binomial Theorem, you have $ \sum_{j=0}^n T(j,n)$ where each $T(j,n)\le 1/j!. $ Therefore $(1+1/n)^n<\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}1/j! $ 
 $<2+1/2$+$\sum_{k=0]^{\infty}$ $2^{-k}/3!$ $=3-1/6<3$.

Comment: @cely 1) Yes, you may interpret it like this. Or just state that your claim and the last inequality are equivalent. 2) Yes.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks. This approach is also nice. I like it.